# Using underscore if statements in Jade templates

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, pug, browserify

I am using `underscore` with `jade`. My build process is convert the `jade templates` into `html`, then from `html` into `underscore` into one `JST` file. Everything is working fine. However there is one problem.

```
//Build process using Gulp
Gulp
  ¬ jade
      ¬ html
          ¬ jst template -> template.js
```

This is working fine, however I am struggling to use if statements whilst using jade:

```
    option(value!='<%= me.value %>', <% if(me.checked === true){ print("selected='selected'"); }%>)
```

I can see its obviously not going to work but I am stuck on how to get this working.

Comment: `me.checked === true? "selected='selected'":""` don`t work?

Comment: But the logic is inside of underscore, not inside jade :O